# Implication of Sobolev inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

For $\varOmega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $n\ge2$, a bounded domain and $1 < q < 2 < p < \frac{2n}{(n-2)_+}$ I want to show that
\begin{equation*}
 \| u \|_{L^p(\varOmega)}^2
 \le C \left( \| \nabla u \|_{L^2(\varOmega)}^2 + \| u \|_{L^q(\varOmega)}^2 \right) 
\end{equation*}
for all $u \in W^{1,2}(\varOmega)$ and some $C > 0$.

I have $\frac1p > \frac{n-2}{2n} = \frac12 - \frac1n$ and from Sobolev embedding
\begin{equation*}
\| u \|_{L^{p}(\varOmega)}^2
 \le C_1 \left( \| \nabla u \|_{L^2(\varOmega)}^2 + \| u \|_{L^2(\varOmega)}^2 \right).
\end{equation*}

I don't know how to conclude the above inequality from this?

Comment: This is not true for all $p>2$. It should work for $p<p^*$ the exponent of Sobolev embedding I presume?

Answer (score 1):

By Hölder's inequality, with $\theta = \frac{1/q-1/2}{1/q-1/p} ∈ (0,1)$, it holds
$$
\|u\|_{L^2} ≤ \|u\|_{L^p}^θ \|u\|_{L^q}^{1-\theta} =: a^θ b^{1-\theta}
$$
and so, since by Young's inequality, for any $\varepsilon>0$,
$$
a^{2θ} b^{2(1-\theta)} = (\varepsilon a^2)^θ \, \varepsilon^{-\theta}\, b^{2(1-\theta)} ≤ \varepsilon \, \theta\, a^2 + \frac{(1-\theta)}{\varepsilon^{\theta/(1-\theta)}}\, b^2.
$$
Starting from your second inequality, one obtains
\begin{align*}
 \|u\|_{L^p}^2
 &\leq C_1 \left(\|\nabla u\|_{L^2}^2 + \|u\|_{L^2}^2 \right)
 \\
 &\leq C_1 \|\nabla u\|_{L^2}^2 + \varepsilon \, \theta\,C_1\, \|u\|_{L^p}^2 + \frac{(1-\theta)\,C_1}{\varepsilon^{\theta/(1-\theta)}}\, \|u\|_{L^q}^2
\end{align*}
and so removing $\varepsilon \, \theta\,C_1\, \|u\|_{L^p}^2$ from both sides leads to
\begin{align*}
 (1-\varepsilon \, \theta\,C_1)\,\|u\|_{L^p}^2
 &\leq C_1 \|\nabla u\|_{L^2}^2 + \frac{(1-\theta)\,C_1}{\varepsilon^{\theta/(1-\theta)}}\, \|u\|_{L^q}^2.
\end{align*}
Taking any $ε < 1/(θ\, C_1)$ and dividing by $1-\varepsilon \, \theta\,C_1 > 0$ on both sides finally yields
\begin{align*}
 \|u\|_{L^p}^2
 &\leq C \left( \|\nabla u\|_{L^2}^2 + \|u\|_{L^q}^2\right),
\end{align*}
with $C = \frac{C_1}{1-\varepsilon \, \theta\,C_1}\max\!\left(1,\frac{(1-\theta)}{\varepsilon^{\theta/(1-\theta)}}\right)$.